# JSF selectBooleanCheckbox always checked

Tags: jsf, mojarra, selectbooleancheckbox

Good afternoon in my timezone.

```
<ui:repeat id="situacoes-edit-list" var="situacao" varStatus="loop" value="#{cc.attrs.managedBean.situacoesEditDTO}">
        <tr  id="sitEdit#{situacao.situacaoId}" class="situations">
             <td colspan = "2">#{situacao.situacaoNome}</td>
        </tr>
  <ui:repeat id="justificacoes-list" var="justificacao" varStatus="innerLoop" value="#{situacao.justificacoes}">
      <tr id="jusEdit#{justificacao.justificacaoId}" class="justifications">
          <td>
              <h:selectBooleanCheckbox  binding="#{chkJust}" id="chk-just-#{chkJust.clientId}" value="#{justificacao.selected}" />
            </td>
             <td>#{justificacao.selected}</td>
      </tr>
  </ui:repeat>
</ui:repeat>
```

In the Bean the the get and set methods are the follow:

```
 public boolean isSelected() {
        return selected;
    }

    public void setSelected(boolean selected) {
        this.selected = selected;
    }
```

The resulting HTML

```
 <tr id="jusEdit6" class="justifications">
      <td><input id="container-edit-form:intervencaoJustificacoes:situacoes-edit-list:0:justificacoes-list:0:chk-just-j_id3" type="checkbox" name="container-edit-form:intervencaoJustificacoes:situacoes-edit-list:0:justificacoes-list:0:chk-just-j_id3" checked="checked" />
       </td>
       <td>false</td>
 </tr>
 <tr id="jusEdit2" class="justifications">
       <td><input id="container-edit-form:intervencaoJustificacoes:situacoes-edit-list:0:justificacoes-list:1:chk-just-j_id3" type="checkbox" name="container-edit-form:intervencaoJustificacoes:situacoes-edit-list:0:justificacoes-list:1:chk-just-j_id3" checked="checked" />
       </td>
       <td>true</td>
</tr>
```

As you see the  `<td>#{justificacao.selected}</td>` returns the correct value but the `value="#{justificacao.selected}"` does not produce the correct behaviour. 
Why is this happening ?
I am using Mojarra 2.0.1

Thanks in advance
Best regards

Comment: Does it work if you don't use binding. Does it work with myfaces? Does it work with a newer version of mojarra?

Comment: And I don't think you can dynamically assign id's this way... it does at least not look like what you intend to get

Comment: There is a bug with this version of Mojarra, it do not let you use this component inside a double repeat